# Importing sharedModule in App and in every Module angular 2

Tags: angular

I am a little confused with how a shared module is imported is used in angular 2 and looking for some clarification.

So when i create  a SharedModule class with imported components and modules which i also export to reuse. I imported the SharedModule into my app.module so: 1. it will be there on app load. 2. so i don't have to import it in other feature modules.

I noticed that even though i imported in my app.module but when i would run my application i get the error message that either i am missing a component or reference to a module. So i end up importing the shared module in all my feature modules. I thought by placing it in the app.module that i wouldn't have to import it in my other modules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I thought by placing it in the app.module that i wouldn't have to import it in my other modules?

No, any modules imported into `AppModule` don't become available to any other Modules also imported by `AppModule`. If you want to have a `SharedModule's` exported Pipes/Components/Directives available to a feature module, the `SharedModule` will have to be imported into that feature module explicitly. The advantage of this is that you have all your exported components in **ONE** module, so even if you had to import the `SharedModule` into 10 Feature Modules, you'd only have to make 1 import, as opposed to importing each Component/Directive/Pipe etc individually in each of those 10 feature modules.

For further reference, check out the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#shared-modules).

Answer (score -1):

If the shared component has Components, Pipes and Directives, you need to import Shared module into each feature module that needs it. As an exception to the above point, you have to import Shared Module in your App module in the below scenario:

- Used Lazy loading, and have a service shared between different feature modules, and there is a need to have a single instance of the service created and shared between the feature modules.

  ```
  import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
  import { SampleService } from './services/sample';

  @NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [],
    exports: []
  })

  export class SharedComponentsModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
      return {
          ngModule: SharedComponentsModule,
          providers: [SampleService]
      };
  }}
  //Import the module with Provider in AppModule :
  Imports: [
  SharedComponentsModule.forRoot()
  ]
  ```